# Why does this polyvariadic function require type annotation?

Tags: haskell, polyvariadic

Here’s a simple polyvariadic function, modelled after `Text.Printf.printf`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}

sumOf :: SumType r => r
sumOf = sum' []

class SumType t where
  sum' :: [Integer] -> t

instance SumType (IO a) where
  sum' args = print (sum args) >> return undefined

instance (SumArg a, SumType r) => SumType (a -> r) where
  sum' args = \a -> sum' (toSumArg a : args)

class SumArg a where 
  toSumArg :: a -> Integer

instance SumArg Integer where 
  toSumArg = id
```

It works fine in ghci without any type annotations:

```
ghci> sumOf 1 2 3
6
```

However, when I remove the `SumArg a` constraint…

```
instance SumType r => SumType (Integer -> r) where
  sum' args = \a -> sum' (toSumArg a : args)
```

…it fails:

```
ghci> sumOf 1 2 3

<interactive>:903:7:
    No instance for (Num a0) arising from the literal `3'
    The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
    Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
    Note: there are several potential instances:
      instance Num Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Num Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
      instance Integral a => Num (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
      ...plus 14 others
    In the third argument of `sumOf', namely `3'
    In the expression: sumOf 1 2 3
    In an equation for `it': it = sumOf 1 2 3
```

How come?

(To be honest, I’m more confused about the fact that the first version *doesn’t* need type annotations on its arguments.)

Comment: The first version doesn't need type annotations because of [extended defaulting](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.6.2/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is because `1` has type `Num n => n`. So when looking for a matching instance for `sumOf 1` it won't match `Integer -> r`. But `a -> r` always matches, so it finds a match in the first case, and in the end, `a` defaults to `Integer`. So I would expect that this works, where `a ~ Integer` forces `a` to become `Integer`:

```
instance (a ~ Integer, SumType r) => SumType (a -> r) where
  sum' args = \a -> sum' (toSumArg a : args)
```

Comment: Oh right, I forgot that constraints don’t affect matching process. Thanks!